# Link a div to a route meteor (Iron Router)

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I would like to "associate a route to a div" with Iron Router without refreshing/changing page. I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I got a div that's not displayed when you arrive in the page (ex: **/home**), but already exists.

When you click on something (box, text, ...), the url changes ( **/home/box1**) and the div appears with some data I'd have given to the route before.
But I would like to be able to do that without having to refresh the page, just to see the div appears in the same page.

So, is it possible with Iron Router and how ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to display the same template on both routes, but only show the div on one of them, you can pass data into the template. The render method takes a second argument which is an object. You set the data property on that object to be a function that returns an object with all of your data values. You can then access them from the template as if they had been defined when inserting the template.

```js
Router.route('/home', function() {
  this.render('Home');
});

Router.route('/home/box1', function() {
  this.render('Home', {
    data: function() {
      return {
        showDiv: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="Main">
  <p>Always showing</p>
  {{#if showDiv}}
    <p>Only showing when on /home/box1 route</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Note: This will not preserve the page you are on regardless of where you are. I.E. If you wanted to do this on the /other and /other/box1 routes. If this is the behavior you're looking for I can help you with that as well.

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for... I'll get back to you once I've tried it on my project and see if it works as I expected. Thanks for your answer :)